# Hiding loading overlay when popup loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension with a popup which shows up when you click on the extension icon. On popup, I have a button which once clicked shows loading box on the currently open tab page.

Screenshot:

[image]

The loading box is removed after some time using `setTimeout`. However this works only when popup itself is VISIBLE. If I click on button on popup and then go to some other tab and come back or click elsewhere on tab page, the popup hides BUT loading box remains visible.

Does any one know how to hide the loading box even if popup goes invisible/out of focus ? I thought it would go away since there is `setTimeout` function which removes it but it doesn't work when popup loses focus.

Instead of pasting all relevant code here, [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11600057/Example.zip) is the download link for the extension so that you could see exactly what I mean.

In actual extension, I have ajax request though instead of `setTimeout`:

```
 $.ajax({
         url : 'localhost url here....',
         data : data, // this is searialized form data
         dataType : 'json',
         method : 'post',
         success : function (r) {
             if (r.success) {
                 window.close();

                 var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
                    'img/48.png',
                    'Done!',
                    'The page has been saved successfully :)'
                 );

                 notification.show();

                 setTimeout(function () {
                     notification.cancel();
                 }, 5000);

             }
             else {
                 if (r.error) {
                     $ediv.text(r.error).fadeIn('fast');
                 }
             }
         },
         error : function (r) {
             $ediv.text('Unknown error, please try again later.').fadeIn('fast');
         },
         complete : function (r) {
             chrome.tabs.executeScript(
                null, {code : "document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('__wnoverlay__'))"}
             );
         }
     });
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: screencast demonstrating the problem: http://www.screenr.com/S2r7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Steps

- Move this AJAX Request to Background Page.
- On Click on Button(Where your dialog box is injected to page) pass message to background Scripts to Store **tab.id**(Check next point).
- Using **tab.id** received from browser action execute your removal dialog box code(Tab id is needed because user can switch his active tab\window any time).

## References

- [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html)
- [Fetching details of active tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-getCurrent)

## EDIT 1

Add following in manifest file ensure you register background and jquery with background Page.

```
"background":{
    "scripts":["js/jquery.js","background.js"]
},
```

Add following code in `background.js`

This code migrates AJAX Call to background Page and executes removal of dialog box after 5 seconds threshold.

```
function invokeAJAX(tabid) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'localhost url here....',
        data: data, // this is searialized form data
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'post',
        success: function (r) {
            if (r.success) {
                window.close();

                var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
                    'img/48.png',
                    'Done!',
                    'The page has been saved successfully :)');

                notification.show();

                setTimeout(function () {
                    notification.cancel();
                }, 5000);

            } else {
                if (r.error) {
                    $ediv.text(r.error).fadeIn('fast');
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (r) {
            $ediv.text('Unknown error, please try again later.').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        complete: function (r) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            tabid, {
                code: "document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('__wnoverlay__'))"
            });
        }
    });

}
```

Your popup.js looks like this where you invoke functions of background Page directly

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    $('#btn').click(function () {

        // show loading message

        // chrome.extension.sendRequest({}, function(response) {});

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            "code": 'var __a=document.createElement("DIV");__a.id="__wnoverlay__";__a.style.width="300px";__a.style.height="80px";__a.style.position="fixed";__a.style.top="50%";__a.style.left="50%";__a.style.color="#fff";__a.style.zIndex=9999999;__a.style.opacity=0.8;__a.style.textAlign="center";__a.style.padding="10px";__a.style.border="12px solid #cccccc";__a.style.marginLeft="-150px";__a.style.marginTop="-40px";__a.style.fontWeight="bold";__a.style.fontSize="17px";__a.style.borderRadius="10px";__a.innerHTML="Working, please wait...";document.body.appendChild(__a);'
        });
        chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tab) {//Get current tab 

            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().invokeAJAX(tab.id);//DO Ajax call and delete div added after 5 sec to current tab only
        });


    });
});
```

## EDIT 2

#### popup.js

Changes made to `popup.js`

- Made tabs.query to fetch only **current active browsing normal** window
- Call back returns tab array so used **tab[0]** index.

After these changes it sends correct message.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        null, {
            "code": 'var __a=document.createElement("DIV");__a.id="__wnoverlay__";__a.style.width="300px";__a.style.height="80px";__a.style.position="fixed";__a.style.top="50%";__a.style.left="50%";__a.style.color="#fff";__a.style.background="url(http://groot.com/WebNote_HTML/ChromeExtension/img/spinner.gif) center no-repeat #999999";__a.style.zIndex=9999999;__a.style.opacity=0.8;__a.style.textAlign="center";__a.style.padding="10px";__a.style.border="12px solid #cccccc";__a.style.marginLeft="-150px";__a.style.marginTop="-40px";__a.style.fontWeight="bold";__a.style.fontSize="17px";__a.style.borderRadius="10px";__a.innerHTML="Working, please wait...";document.body.appendChild(__a);'
        });
        //Proper Query Formation    
        chrome.tabs.query({
            "active": true,
            "status": "complete",
            "currentWindow": true,
            "windowType": "normal"
        }, function (tab) { //Get current tab
            //DO Ajax call
            //tab is an array so we need to access its first index
            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().invokeAJAX(tab[0].id, $this.closest('form').serialize());
        });

    });

});
```

#### background.js

Changes made to `background.js`

- Eliminated `$ediv.text` code references as it is undefined in background page.

After these changes this is final code.

```
 function invokeAJAX(tabid, data) {

     data = data || '';

     $.ajax({
         url: 'http://groot.com/WebNote_HTML/ChromeExtension/savePage.php',
         data: data,
         dataType: 'json',
         method: 'post',
         success: function (r) {
             if (r.success) {
                 // window.close();

                 var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification(
                     'img/48.png',
                     'Done!',
                     'The page has been saved successfully :)');

                 notification.show();

                 setTimeout(function () {
                     notification.cancel();
                 }, 5000);

             } else {
                 if (r.error) {
                     //$ediv.text(r.error).fadeIn('fast');
                     console.log("Error .." + r);
                 }
             }
         },
         error: function (r) {
             //$ediv.text('Unknown error, please try again later.').fadeIn('fast');
             console.log("Error .." + r);
         },
         complete: function (r) {
             chrome.tabs.executeScript(
             tabid, {
                 code: "document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('__wnoverlay__'))"
             });
         }
     });

 }
```

## EDIT 3

```
$('#btn').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    //Proper Query Formation    
    chrome.tabs.query({
        "active": true,
        "status": "complete",
        "currentWindow": true,
        "windowType": "normal"
    }, function (tab) { //Get current tab
        //DO Ajax call
        //tab is an array so we need to access its first index
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(
        tab[0].id, {
            "code": 'var __a=document.createElement("DIV");__a.id="__wnoverlay__";__a.style.width="300px";__a.style.height="80px";__a.style.position="fixed";__a.style.top="50%";__a.style.left="50%";__a.style.color="#fff";__a.style.background="url(http://groot.com/WebNote_HTML/ChromeExtension/img/spinner.gif) center no-repeat #999999";__a.style.zIndex=9999999;__a.style.opacity=0.8;__a.style.textAlign="center";__a.style.padding="10px";__a.style.border="12px solid #cccccc";__a.style.marginLeft="-150px";__a.style.marginTop="-40px";__a.style.fontWeight="bold";__a.style.fontSize="17px";__a.style.borderRadius="10px";__a.innerHTML="Working, please wait...";document.body.appendChild(__a);'
        });
        $('#url').val(tab[0].url);
        $('#title').val(tab[0].title);
        $loader.hide();
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().invokeAJAX(tab[0].id, $this.closest('form').serialize());
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you elobarate a little more in terms of code or little demo please. I have confusion about background pages and content scripts, etc

Comment: @dev02: Are you executing this ajax call on click of button??

Comment: Yes it runs on button click.

Comment: @dev02: I have added a working version prototype as my **EDIT 1**, hope this helps :)

Comment: Unfortuantely when clicking on button I am getting `Reference error: data is not defined` even though i am passing it like this: `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().invokeAJAX(tab.id, $(this).closest('form').serialize());` and then using it via function like `invokeAJAX(tabid, data)` but inside that ajax function, it says it isn't defined :(

Comment: I guess you need to wait for `$(this).closest('form').serialize()` to complete and pass it to `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().invokeAJAX` after it is done with processing

Comment: It was cahching issue, fixed. However the visiblity problem still persists when you click on button loader is shown and then if you click elsewhere on page popup hides but then loader never goes away and ajax request isn't triggered if popup goes invsible. I loose from chrome extensions :(

Comment: All I am trying to do is a way to notify extension users (through any method) about whatever ajax response was returned even if popup goes invisible.

Comment: @dev02: Post your present state of code, will try helping you :)

Comment: @dev02:Check my **EDIT 2**, i have added a tested working version, hope this helps :)

Comment: Getting `Cannot call method 'invokeAJAX' of null `

Comment: The issue is: Once you click on button on popup, the loader div shows on page at then quickly click any where on open page and popup hides. Now when popup hides, nothing happens, no ajax request being triggered and loading div is always visible eg never goes away

Comment: @dev02: I have just checked the issue, it is working when i quickly close popup, have you used my code as i copied, without changes?

Comment: Yes using that code but issue is there as i mentioned. can you zip that code somewhere for me to try out so as to make sure iam not missing anything

Comment: Here is my full extension related code: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11600057/ChromeExtension.zip

Comment: @dev02: Your code is properly working for me ,i clicked on submit and closed popup at maximum speed an abnormal user closes :) :) and waited for nearly 6-10 seconds and it is cleared,what is time frame you waited?

Comment: i have waited for even 10 minutes. In others words, it doesnt work giving error `Cannot call method 'invokeAJAX' of null` meaning when popup hides, background page is also null which is why that error comes

Comment: @dev02:Can you put a screen cast recording, i am surprised to see error on your front, BTW its past 2 early morning in my time zone, will check in my early morning today :) :)

Comment: @dev02: You are running code on `localhost` pages, can you try the same code in some **http** or **https** protocol? Check My **EDIT 3** for updated code use it and let me know if it is still failing!

Comment: You were right, I was always trying it on local URLs assuming it should work on those as well. Tried it on non-local URLs and it worked like a charm. Thanks man for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

The popup code stops executing when the is not shown. However, the injected code is always executed. So you should set the timeout in the injected code, like this:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {"code": 'setTimeout(function(){ document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("__wnoverlay__")); }, 5000)'});
```

Replace the code from line 13-15 with the above code and it should work.

Comment: Hi thanks. In real extension I have an ajax request instead of setTimeout. How would I hide loading message once ajax request has finsihed in that case ?

Comment: @dev02: Have you tried adding in success handler of ajax request.?

Comment: @Sudarshan: Yes i have added success as well as complete handlers where I have put code to hide loading box. This works only when popup is in focus. You can download the extension and check it out for yourself.

Comment: @dev02:I have downloaded your extension, but there is no AJAX request in that? did you link correct file..

Comment: @Sudarshan: I have posted actual ajax request in the question

Comment: @dev02:Check my answer for this problem

Comment: @dev2 You should see Sudarshan's answer, it should solve your problem